# Should I explain my "NP" grade in my statement of purpose?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, application, statement-of-purpose

Here's my situation. I am struggling with it for weeks. I am a math major applying to Ph.D. programs (pure math). I have a 3.94 major GPA, but in my sophomore year, I got an NP (no pass) in a math course of differential geometry. This is because I didn't make the final for personal reasons. I retook the course (in my junior year, because there is only one such course a year) and got an A, and actually I got full marks in all quizzes and exams.

Here is the thing. Do I need to explain in my "NP" grade in my statement of purpose? Since I am applying to good Ph.D. programs, my statement of purpose is like a research statement, and it shows my math background, research experience, and dedication - all good things. I feel it is very weird to write anything about my "NP" in such a statement. I also feel like professors don't like such things showing up in a statement of purpose.

If I don't write any explanation, I believe that professors will know the "NP" cannot reflect my academic ability. After all, I retook it and nearly all my math courses are "A". However, I am worried that they make some guesses about the "NP" like academic dishonesty (definitely not true), or I don't have the ability to handle the crisis (which is true). Besides, I think (only my guess) professors will be curious about it, so maybe they are expecting an explanation?

All in all, should I explain my "NP" grade in my statement of purpose?

Comment: Is this question related to a particular country?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in the US, particularly for weak or borderline students?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-ph-d-programs-in-the-us-particularly)

Answer (score 3):

This sort of thing is always a strategic decision. While some readers will appreciate the clarification, for others it may serve to highlight something that would otherwise not have attracted attention. I suggest seeking advice from professors at your current institution, who can comment on how your overall application looks.

If you do decide to address it, some options include:

1. Ask one of your letter-writers if they can deal with it in their letter;
2. Add a standalone note at the end of your Statement of Purpose. Don't work it into the prose of your SoP, just put something at the end such as

> N.B. The 'NP' grade shown on my transcript for ... arose because I was unable to attend the final exam for personal reasons. I retook this course in .... and received an 'A'.

3. Include a cover note with the transcript.

Good luck!